# Steps or evaluation order of the SQL statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

How the SQL statement containing simple statement like

```
Select x
From y
Where z
```

`Having,` `order by` , `group by` etc. are evaluated.( In which order they are evaluated.?)

Answer (score 1):

Following is the logical order of execution of the SQL clauses:

> 1. FROM clause
> 2. WHERE clause
> 3. GROUP BY clause
> 4. HAVING clause
> 5. SELECT clause
> 6. ORDER BY clause

Comment: Is Logical order of SQL clauses is same for MSSQL and MySQL?

Comment: http://www.zazzle.com/sql_queries_explained_coffee_mug-168973002678226909 (not a plug, no affiliation)